# fa fa-search non-responsive in mac and iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

I have used search icon of font awesome fa fa-search, It works on all browser, All Android phones, But not in mac and iPhone. I am not able to click icon in all apple related devices and browser.

Also there is no console error in browser, In iPhone i cant click on it. 
Thanks in advance !!!

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="searchMobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Artist / Keyword" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <a id="searchMobileButton" onclick="searchMobile();" class="btn btn-secondary text-white" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Font Awesome you using?

Comment: Hi,  v4.7.0 https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/search

Comment: iF i remember well, you must have a href="#" in your a-tag for Apple to accept it as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below link in header element,

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And add the below css in your customicon.css,

```
@font-face {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Comment: @whoviralmistry I edited my answer. Can you just try that?